# Pythagorean triple nested loops missunderstanding

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, computer-science

Greetings and regards;

I was trying to find ***Pythagorean Triple*** numbers less than **1000**.

Fortunately I was able to find the algorithm for it, Here it is:

```
for (int a = 1; a < 1000; a++)
{
    for (int b = a; b < 1000; b++)
    {
        for (int c = b; c < 1000; c++)
        {
            if ((a * a) + (b * b) == (c * c))
            {
                cout << "( " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << " )";
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand a thing about this code!
Why does the initial value of each loop start from the value of the previous loop ? While the initial value of each loops can be started from **1** !

What's the reason for this ?

Comment: Have you try to debug/execute this and check the output to understand?

Comment: I did, but i didn't understand.

Comment: A Pythagorean triple consists of three positive integers a, b, and c. From this, search for tutorials on how to calculate, and go over the code, execute the code, provide inputs and check the results,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythagorean triplets have only one way of being ordered: if `a² + b² = c²` then one can prove than `a² + c² ≠ b²` and `b² + c² ≠ a²`.

From the above and a few special cases (`a = 0` is excluded by definition, `a ∊ (0, 2]` are easy to check by hand), it follows that one only has to check triplets for which `2 < a ≤ b < c`, and this is (almost) what the tree loops do.

There are two reasons for this:

1. By setting up the loop so that `a ≤ b ≤ c` we guarantee that no triplet appears more than once
2. There are fewer triplets to test, so we reduce the execution time by a constant factor.

Comment: I think there is a typo. Do you mean `a ∊ (0, 2]` rather than `a ∊ [0, 2]`? 0 is obviously excluded from the permitted values, because otherwise the set of triplets would trivially include `0, i, i` for all (non-negative) integers `i`.

Comment: As you say, 0 can be trivially excluded, as can 1 and 2. Granted, 0 is excluded for a different reason, but it doesn't change anything to the end result.

Comment: I just meant that 0 does not need to be checked by hand because it is excluded _by definition_.  Anyway, as you say, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

**For a < b :**

Pythagorean triples appear in pairs i.e. (a,b,c) and (b,a,c) : a,b < c ∀ a,b,c ∈ ℕ. Since other one of the pair becomes a trivial solution if one is found. Suppose a Pythagorean triple (a,b,c) is found such that a < b then we immediately know that (b,a,c) is also a Pythagorean triple so we don't want our program to search for it as it will just increase the search domain and thus the execution time. To avoid that, loops are set as a≤b. However, you can also initiate them as a < b or b = a + 1

**For b < c or a < b < c:**

You can initiate them as a < b < c or (c = b + 1 and b = a + 1) because no Pythagorean triple can be of form (b,b,c) as b^2 + b^2 = 2 * b^2 = c^2, that means c = b * sqrt(2) in which c is an integer and b * sqrt(2) is an irrational number, so the two can never be equal and integer solution can never exist. But c = b * sqrt(2) also says that c > b.

**Therefore, a < b < c**